# MySQL error while trying to create table,

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using PHPMyAdmin, hosted with hostgator, to add a table to a database, but I keep getting the following error:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL , `note` TEXT NOT NULL , `cardNumber` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `nameC' at line 1

Here's what I have:
[image]
and here's the preview of the SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `nightwin_mark-inn`.`guests` (
    `id` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `dateIn` DATE NOT NULL , 
    `dateOut` DATE NOT NULL , 
    `email` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `phone` INT(10) NOT NULL , 
    `room` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL , 
    `price` DOUBLE(6) NOT NULL , 
    `note` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `cardNumber` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , 
    `nameCard` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `expDate` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `cvc` TINYINT(3) NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

What's causing this issue? Do I have the length of one of the fields wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - `DOUBLE(6)` should be only `DOUBLE`

```
CREATE TABLE `nightwin_mark-inn`.`guests` ( `id` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`dateIn` DATE NOT NULL , `dateOut` DATE NOT NULL , `email` TEXT NOT NULL , 
`phone` INT(10) NOT NULL , `room` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL , `price` DOUBLE NOT NULL , 
`note` TEXT NOT NULL , `cardNumber` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `nameCard` TEXT NOT NULL , 
 `expDate` TEXT NOT NULL , `cvc` TINYINT(3) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

Comment: this works, thanks! I had a feeling it was improper setting of length. I'll accept the answer when it allows me too.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this

```
price` DOUBLE(6,2) NOT NULL   //9999.99 max value stored
```

instead of

```
price` DOUBLE(6) NOT NULL
```

> Note: for price field use datatype **DECIMAL** more preferable. In **FLOAT** or **DOUBLE** datatype you will get rounding number issue

**[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html)**

Comment: This is the only Answer (so far) that points out that `DOUBLE` is not good for money.

Answer (score 0):

```
please try using this MySQL statement

CREATE TABLE `guests` ( `id` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  `dateIn` DATE NOT NULL , `dateOut` DATE NOT NULL , `email` TEXT NOT NULL ,  `phone` INT(10) NOT NULL , `room` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL , `price` DOUBLE(6,2) NOT NULL ,  `note` TEXT NOT NULL , `cardNumber` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `nameCard` TEXT NOT NULL ,      `expDate` TEXT NOT NULL , `cvc` TINYINT(3) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Answer (score 0):

please try using this MySQL statement

CREATE TABLE `guests` ( `id` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  `dateIn` DATE NOT NULL , `dateOut` DATE NOT NULL , `email` TEXT NOT NULL ,  `phone` INT(10) NOT NULL , `room` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL , `price` DOUBLE(6,2) NOT NULL ,  `note` TEXT NOT NULL , `cardNumber` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , `nameCard` TEXT NOT NULL ,      `expDate` TEXT NOT NULL , `cvc` TINYINT(3) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`));